# Is the phrase "Shape outlines of something" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, expressions, collocation

Is the phrase "shaped the outlines"  grammatically correct in this sentence? I want it to indicate that this subject played a key role in shaping my interests:

> By introducing leading approaches to observe and evaluate conditions
>   of internal body organs through techniques that limit the use of
>   invasive clinical procedures, this course shaped the outlines of my
>   desired discipline and career.

Comment: zpl donna be uzn brv8snz @ELU, ktnxbai

Comment: The first part of your sentence could be tightened, I think. I see where you want to go, but rather than _shaped the outlines_, how about simply _outlined, gave contour to,_ or even _gave direction to_?

Comment: @KarlG You're right, The first part is too long but I don't know how to keep it shorter while losing no valuable details.

Comment: @KarlG Outline as a verb seems ok but I don't want it to convey that this subject was the only source of shaping my future. By saying "shaping the outlines", I wanted it to sound more like the whole general idea was being formed slowly rather than all the outlines being shaped at once merely by this course.

Comment: Then _gave contour_ would be a better choice, that is, helping to give shape, precision to your career plans/goals.

Comment: @Ghazal.S It seems you should explore other ways of stating your idea. Even when grammatically speaking the phrase is not wrong, it does not make for easy reading. You may want to take a paper and write 5 to 10 possible ways of expressing your thoughts. It is hard work, but it always payback in many ways. From there, you can then start eliminating.

Comment: I wouldn't say you've violated any grammar rules, but I'd cut it back to "shaped my desired discipline and career". When speaking metaphorically about something abstract or amorphous, a thing's outline _is_ its shape.

Comment: The first part might be easier to parse if you start with “This course ...” otherwise we have to work through  the complicated wording without even knowing what it is about! And, like others, using both shape and outline seems redundant and lacks clarity.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the phrase "shaped the outlines" necessarily, per the word's definition:

[American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=shape)

> 4. a. To influence in a formative way.
> 5. b. To direct the course of.

But it could be argued that the immediate addition of the phrase "of my desired discipline and career" makes it unnecessarily wordy (why not just "shaped my desired discipline and career"?).